# python - How to read data fully from serial port?

Tags: python, string, io, serial-port, pyserial

I'm trying to read a JSON string written to serial port, using the following code based on `PySerial` library:

```
while True:
    if serial_port.in_waiting > 0:
        buffer = serial_port.readline()
        print('buffer=', buffer)
        ascii = buffer.decode('ascii')
        print('ascii=', ascii)
```

I tried to sniff the data on the port, and got sure that the data gets written fully without any scattering:

```
jpnevulator --ascii --tty "/dev/ttyACM1" --read
7B 22 30 22 3A 31 7D                            {"0":1}
7B 22 30 22 3A 32 7D                            {"0":2}
7B 22 30 22 3A 33 7D                            {"0":3}
7B 22 30 22 3A 34 7D                            {"0":4}
7B 22 30 22 3A 35 7D                            {"0":5}
7B 22 30 22 3A 36 7D                            {"0":6}
```

However the used code results in scattered data read, and therefore shows the following results:

```
buffer= b'{"0'
ascii= {"0
buffer= b'":1}'
ascii= ":1}
buffer= b'{"'
ascii= {"
buffer= b'0":2'
ascii= 0":2
buffer= b'}'
ascii= }
```

Also, when I use `read()` instead of `readline()`, I get the same behavior:

```
buffer= b'{'
data_str= {
buffer= b'"'
data_str= "
buffer= b'3'
data_str= 3
buffer= b'"'
data_str= "
buffer= b':'
data_str= :
buffer= b'1'
data_str= 1
buffer= b'}'
data_str= }
```

I even tried using [another code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adamwtow/python-serial-monitor/master/python-serial-monitor.py) that uses the same library, but got the same issue.

I'm not sure why I'm encountering such behavior.

Comment: Readline() is probably not what you are after, as it doesnt appear that your data is terminated with a linefeed, "\n", so try read() Instead, 

Equally you may just be too impatient, the serial port will say there is data there when it has only received the first character, so your buffer.decode may behave weirdly when only fed 1 or 2 characters

Comment: @Reroute As I pointed out in the edit, using `read()` rather doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: As @Reroute suggested at the end of their comment. You take an action immediately once there is any input available (`.in_waiting > 0`). Is there any way for you to tell you got a full "message" and read only then? Alternatively... you could still read piece by piece, but you have to assemble the desired content yourself.. I.e. collect until closing brace, then start new `ascii`. Are you inputs fixed size? That would make your life much easier. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll attempt to tackle this. :) Your loop wait for any input to become available `serial_port.in_waiting > 0`. Hence the behavior you are seeing. The read will start once anything can be acquired. It does not appear that `PySerial` would have any additional abstraction available to let your know something like last readied byte would be an ASCII curly brace character (I've really just scanned through the docs). You can always apply a generic solution of read as stuff comes and make sense out of it inside your Python script.

One question first though. Your input example suggest you'd be dealing with equally sized string / JSON? Should we be really that lucky? If so, you could wait until that or more bytes are available and read just the desired size into your `buffer`.

Otherwise a variation on your code:

```
buffer = bytes()  # .read() returns bytes right?
while True:
    if serial_port.in_waiting > 0:
        buffer += serial_port.read(serial_port.in_waiting)
        try:
            complete = buffer[:buffer.index(b'}')+1]  # get up to '}'
            buffer = buffer[buffer.index(b'}')+1:]  # leave the rest in buffer
        except ValueError:
            continue  # Go back and keep reading
        print('buffer=', complete)
        ascii = buffer.decode('ascii')
        print('ascii=', ascii)
```

NOTE1: I presume `serial_port.in_waiting` could in theory change between the if and read, but I also presume unread bytes just stay on buffer and we're fine.

NOTE2: This approach is a bit naive and does not take into account that you could have also read two chunks of JSON code.

NOTE3: And it also does not account for nested mappings in your JSON if that is the case.

Hopefully it's still helpful. Bottom line. Unless handling fixed size inputs or getting any other way to have `pySerial` feed you content chunked as desired, you have to read stuff in and process it in your script.

---

UPDATE: To reflect the discussion in the comments.

Your problem really is that you are just looking at (stream of) bytes on the serial port. At that level there isn't any useful understanding of the data  being passed through. You need a higher level (application or a layer in between) making sense out of the what is coming in. In other words, to parse the protocol that encapsulates the data transferred.

As a matter of fact, if we know string (bunch of bytes) representing JSON is what is passed through (servers as protocol, way to encapsulate/represent data (structures)), that can work, but the reassembly needs to happen above the raw serial communication. Our application (or library / module) can read the raw serial data, make sense out of it and provide them to the higher levels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The inputs are not fixed sized, and they are needed to be retrieved at once. Unfortunately, this concatenation approach will fail when different writes are happening in near time (*overlapping scattered reads from different buffers*).

Comment: In that case, you'd need a different trigger to perform the read then just `serial_port.in_waiting` becoming non-zero. You need to know not just that any/first byte(s) are available, but rather complete data "chunk" is ready.

Comment: Now it shows single character per read - This is the code I made to address what you are meaning: https://gist.github.com/kaisbe/281b5eef1edffa82d1427b0d7b913e6c.

Comment: Can we confirm that it's not possible to retrieve a buffer at once using PySerial, without chunks?

Comment: I've just scanned through its docs and I did not see anything that would suggest any other signaling facility. But it really does make sense. If you just look at the serial interface, you get (stream of) bytes. You cannot do anything else without additional information, some protocol encapsulating your content saying, I start here, I am done here. Which would be application specific and handled in the application I presume. Opening and closing braces could serve that purpose for instance. But I dunno your setup and there could be more to it then just a stream I could read and parse as I wish.

Comment: So in other words. As is, Yes, without more detail regarding the setup and a bit creativity. I am afraid you won't be able to just `.read()` and get exactly one JSON representing string.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I understand now, how things work - this is due to the nature of serial communication. Could you please update your answer, so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem in data communication: *When has a complete frame been received?*

If you have control over both sides, I would suggest that you add extra framing to the protocol. Otherwise you need to check character by character if you have received a complete JSON object.

A very simple protocol is [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/), which only requires you to add `'\n'` between frames, and refrain from inserting newlines in your payload. If you have actual newlines inside a JSON string, they will automatically be escaped if you are using a JSON library.

Example writer:

```
# Writing ndjson frames
frames = [
    {"0": "1"},
    {"0": "2"},
]
for frame in frames:
    port.write(json.dumps(frame, separators=(',', ':')))  # No extra whitespace or newlines
    port.write('\n')  # ndjson protocol separator
```

An ndjson framed stream can be read using [`pyserial.readline()`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#readline).

Note that you need to specify a timeout to be able to exit your program as `readline()` will otherwise block forever.

Example reader assuming `port` is opened with a timeout:

```
while True:
    data = port.readline()  # Blocks until a complete frame is received or timeout
    if data:
        d = json.loads(data)
        print("Received object: %r" % d)
    else:
        if should_exit:
            break
```